# Special case of testing integer polynomials for irreducibility

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms, polynomials

How much easier is testing polynomials of the form x^n + ax + b for irreducibility (in Z[x]) than testing polynomials in general? I am especially interested in the case where n is prime, which may be easier than the case of arbitrary n.

Comment: An immediate special sub-case is the "Artin-Schreier" polynomials $x^p-x+a$, for $p$ prime, which are irreducible for $a\in\mathbb Z$ not divisible by $p$, because they are irreducible mod $p$.

Comment: I only know the generalized Eisenstein criterion *Van der Waerden, 2nd.ed, p76-77), essentially that if a prime q exists whose highest power dividing b is q^k, where k is not a multiple of p, and if q^k also divides a, then irreducibility follows, (assuming n=p is prime).  e.g. X^5 + 12X + 4.

Moreover if X^n + pX + cp^2 is irreducible, then it has a linear factor.  e.g. X^6 + 3X + 9 has no root mod 5 hence is irreducible.  I hope this is right, as I am a novice.

Answer (score 1):

For a special case (when $a=\pm 1$) see

[About irreducible trinomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56579/about-irreducible-trinomials)

Testing irreducibilty over small moduli (obviously, if your polynomial is irreducible modulo $p,$ it is irreducible), is described in detail in [this paper of Richard Brent's.](http://wwwmaths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/QMt4.pdf)