# Irreducibility of the trinomial over Q

Tags: polynomials, number-fields

I'm trying to find an algebraic proof of irreducibility of the polynomial $x^n-x-1$ over rational numbers (or integers, which the same). I've read the Selmer's paper "On the irreducibility of certain trinomials", and I got his idea, but... In his proof he uses analysis methods. I wonder, if the pure algebraic proof exists? I mean, without making graphics and curves, but studying polynomial as the element of Q[x], not as a function.

Comment: In the right hand column of this page you'll see a list of related questions that have been asked before; some of them look like they might be helpful.  In particular, the question "About irreducible trinomials" has an answer pointing to a paper by Ljunggren.  There is not an obvious route to an online copy, but the Math Review says that "The methods used are direct and elementary".

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56579/about-irreducible-trinomials


Comment: "direct and elementary" doesn't necessarily mean avoiding the use of elementary calculus, which I imagine is the only analysis Selmer uses (to get information about the real roots).  So, I wouldn't say that this answers the question unless someone who has access to the paper can tell us more about what it uses.

Comment: I looked at the paper by Ljunggren ("On the irreducibility of certain trinomials and quadrinomials." 
Math. Scand. 8 1960 65–70.) He only uses basic algebra, as far as I can tell.  

Comment: Here is the link to the paper: http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1564

Comment: It answers also Selmer's second case: $x^n+x+1$ is irreducible for $n\ge 2$ if and only if not $n\equiv 2\mod 3$

Comment: Thank you very much! Ljunggren's paper is exactly what I needed.

Comment: In Osada's paper *The Galois groups of the polynomials $x^n+ax^l+b$*, Journal of Number Theory, Volume 25, Issue 2, February 1987, Pages 230–238, the author proves that all your polynomials have symmetric Galois group, for what it's worth. (Edit: This should have been a comment rather than an answer -- when I posted this I didn't realize that Osada just cites Selmer for the irreducibility part, as pointed out by Joni Teräväinen.) Here is a link: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X87900291 Look at Lemma 7 and Corollary 3. I would describe the techniques as algebraic.

Comment: I can't find the proof of Lemma 7 (which is this question) in the paper. Instead, it seems that the paper refers to Selmer.

Comment: Oops.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MarkSapir: Your link to Ljunggren's paper is broken. Two links I found that work (for now) are http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10593/8614 and http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/math/article/viewFile/10593/8614.

Answer (score 3):

For an algebraic approach to the irreducibility, see the sketch I wrote as an answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393646/irreducibility-of-xn-x-1-over-mathbb-q.